# Python nested dictionaries key,value swap

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, key-value

I recently began to work with Python and with the following example I spent so much time to not figure it out so I decide to ask you guys if you can help.

So, I have a Dictionary with username and email pairs but my problem is that since it is not a single key:value pair, I couldn't merge them into one.

```
9978 {u'': u'TERRY.HERREGON@EXAMPLE.COM', u'USD38020': u''}
9979 {u'': u'REMKO.VON.DER.WURF@ABV.COM', u'GELREM01': u''}
9980 {u'': u'MARTIN.YGOR@ANTEL.COM'}
9981 {u'': u'DON.VASSILLI@TEST.COM', u'AUVASSILIDE': u''}
9982 {u'': u'JAMES.WOJOCICK@SUN.COM', u'JAMES.WOJCIK': u''}
9983 {u'': u'DANIEL.MUCHANA@JAVA.COM', u'DEHDAMU': u''}
```

What I want to do here is to assign the Username Key to the Email Value and have only one pair.
As you can see there is a dict that has no username. It looks like that because there was no entry in my database.
If anyone has any ideas, it will be much appreciated. My solution would look like this:

```
9978 {u'USD38020': u'TERRY.HERREGON@EXAMPLE.COM'}
9979 {u'GELREM01': u'REMKO.VON.DER.WURF@ABV.COM'}
9980 {u'': u'MARTIN.YGOR@ANTEL.COM'}
9981 {u'AUVASSILIDE': u'DON.VASSILLI@TEST.COM'}
9982 {u'JAMES.WOJCIK': u'JAMES.WOJOCICK@SUN.COM'}
9983 {u'DEHDAMU': u'DANIEL.MUCHANA@JAVA.COM'}
```

Comment: Can you share the code that generates the first dictionary in the first place? It would probably be easier to generate the desired dictionary in the first place instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to search for a key that is not empty in each dictionary, then use the value from the empty-string key to create a new dictionary:

```
new_d = {next((k for k in d.iterkeys() if k), u''): d['']}
```

The `next()` call returns either the first non-empty key, or the empty `u''` string. The value is always set to `d['']`.

Demo:

```
>>> sample = [
...     {u'': u'TERRY.HERREGON@EXAMPLE.COM', u'USD38020': u''},
...     {u'': u'REMKO.VON.DER.WURF@ABV.COM', u'GELREM01': u''},
...     {u'': u'MARTIN.YGOR@ANTEL.COM'},
...     {u'': u'DON.VASSILLI@TEST.COM', u'AUVASSILIDE': u''},
...     {u'': u'JAMES.WOJOCICK@SUN.COM', u'JAMES.WOJCIK': u''},
...     {u'': u'DANIEL.MUCHANA@JAVA.COM', u'DEHDAMU': u''},
... ]
>>> for d in sample:
...     print {next((k for k in d.iterkeys() if k), u''): d['']}
... 
{u'USD38020': u'TERRY.HERREGON@EXAMPLE.COM'}
{u'GELREM01': u'REMKO.VON.DER.WURF@ABV.COM'}
{u'': u'MARTIN.YGOR@ANTEL.COM'}
{u'AUVASSILIDE': u'DON.VASSILLI@TEST.COM'}
{u'JAMES.WOJCIK': u'JAMES.WOJOCICK@SUN.COM'}
{u'DEHDAMU': u'DANIEL.MUCHANA@JAVA.COM'}
```